# Loosing pointer in subclass after copy

Tags: c++, class, pointers, c++11, copy

I have 2 classes:

```
class CCandidate {
public:
    float score;
    BitSet documents;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > phrases;
    int cardinality;

    /** For merging. */
    CCandidate()
    : score(0.0), documents(1), phrases(1), cardinality(0) {}

    /** */
    CCandidate(
    std::vector<int>& phraseIndices, BitSet& documents,
    int cardinality, float score) {

    this->phrases.reserve(1);
    this->phrases.push_back(phraseIndices);

    this->documents = documents;
    this->score = score;
    this->cardinality = cardinality;
    }
};

class PCandidate {
public:
    CCandidate * topics;
    float coverage;

    bool selected;
    bool mostGeneral;
    bool mostSpecific;

    PCandidate(CCandidate * c, float coverage)
    : topics(c), coverage(coverage), 
      selected(true), mostGeneral(true), mostSpecific(true) {}
};
```

In another class where these classes are used I have something like this:

```
// ...
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<PCandidate> > phrases(mergeList.size());

for (size_t i = 0; i < mergeList.size(); i++) {
    CCandidate * cc = baseTopics.at(mergeList.get(i));
    std::wcout << cc->toString() << std::endl;
    float coverage = cc->cardinality / result->cardinality;
    std::wcout << "coverage=" << coverage << std::endl;
    phrases.push_back(std::make_shared<PCandidate>(PCandidate(cc, coverage)));

    std::for_each(phrases.begin(), phrases.end(),
        [&](const std::shared_ptr<PCandidate>& pc) { 
            std::wcout << pc->toString() << " "; }); // error
    }
}

anotherMethod(phrases);

// ...
```

Everything is fine with the CCandidate `cc` (for now in this verson it is a raw pointer), I can print its contents (method toString() not copied in here) and all is fine. Then I construct the PCandidate Object with the `make_shared`, push it into the phrases vector and when try to access that `phrases' vector to show me the contents of Pcandidate, the topics cluster I get an segmentation fault.

I could not do something like

```
std::wcout << ptr->topics->phrases.size() << std::endl
```

where `ptr` is a pointer to `PCandidate`. `topics` is a pointer to CCandidate containing the phrases vector.

It will give me

```
==10013== Invalid read of size 8
```

to see the size of the phrases vector in CCandidate.

I'm a little lost as I do not now where to track down the problem, sitting at this since yesterday. It might be a bloody beginners mistake. Is the lack of missing copy constructors / assignment operators? If yes how should they look like? For example copy the entire phrases vector, like a deep copy? I thought the default copy/assignment should be OK so far.

Would be great if somebody can show me the error or how to fix this! Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: @DrewDormann: Exactly. I edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: What does `std::wcout << ptr` output?  What about `std::wcout << ptr->topics`?

Comment: @DrewDormann: ptr is a pointer to `PCandidate`. `PCandidate` has a pointer to `CCandidate` class. So if I want to print the `size()` of the phrases vector of `CCandidate`, I would do a `ptr->topics->phrases.size()`. As you see in the for loop, a copy of `CCandidate` is saved into `PCandidate`.

Comment: One of those pointers is not what you think.  That's why I'm asking.  You should check.

Comment: A copy is *not* saved in PCandidate; a raw pointer to the original *is*. What is the type stored in `mergeList()` per-chance?

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, so why can't I access above mentioned phrases vector? I need to have a pointer of `CCandidate` inside `PCandidate` to assign clusters or topics (CCandidate) to identify to what topics this phrase belongs to. `mergeList` contains a list of merged `CCandidates`.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced the pointer your getting is truly valid. Just because it was deleted (whether you know it or not) doesn't mean you can`t trip into the land of undefined behavior and access the memory formerly under it anyway. Knowing `baseTopics` type would be helpful as well. In the meantime, I would breakpoint the destructor for CCandidate and, if one is implemented for PCandidate but conveniently omitted in the pasted source, breakpoint it too. Still waiting on something that we can *compile*.

Comment: And if you want to just get to the heart of it **valgrind** ftw.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I can not reduce it down to a code that compiles, I wish I could provide such source, but is is to huge. So I though it would be possible to identify the problem on these snippets. Fact is inside the loop I can access the pointer `CCandidate * cc` and print its contents with no problem. As soon as it gets into the phrases vector via make_shared making the PCandidate object, I can not access it anymore (via the CCandidate * topics) pointer. So here should be the basic problem, but I do nt understand where the problem is. I use valgrind. "Invalid read of size 8" is from valgrind.

Comment: As I said before, just because you can access it doesn't mean its valid. And as I said before, the *types* of everything not self-documenting in the code as-presented are about the only thing that is going to get this moved along any further. Currently `baseTopics`, `mergeList`, `phrases, and the *complete* definition of `PCandidate` continue to remain a mystery. In their implementation is the answer to your question.

Comment: Unlikely to solve your problem (but might hide it), you could have a `phrases.reserve(mergeList.size())` before you populate it. As it stands, you might be doing a _lot_ of copying of `shared_ptr<>`

Comment: @WhozCraig: The Defintion of `PCandidate` and also `CCandidate` is complete, the code you see in my question is the complete class with its implementation. Its nothing more than a holder. I skipped to add the toString methods, that all. `baseTopics` is a vector containing objects of type `CCandidate`. That list is constructed before I call the method containing such loop above. `baseTopics` is passed as a reference to that function containing above loop `std::vector<CCandidate *>& baseTopics`. mergeList is basically a integer stack (made with vector<int>). I edited my question.

Comment: @Keith: Yes, I am doing this already before the loop (just added the line in the code snippet in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're populating your `phrases` vector initially with `mergeList.size()` **NULL** shared-pointers, then pushing the *real* ones in *after* those.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<PCandidate> > phrases(mergeList.size());
```

So the first `mergeList.size()` pointers in your vector are NULL. Lose the initial sizing.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<PCandidate> > phrases;
```

If you want to reserve capacity, you can, but ultimately the shared pointers are still going to have to go through their reference counting algorithm either way. I'd skip it and just do the above.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! I removed the initial size and now that part is running fine! Thanks for that hint!